# Does water produce electromagnetic radiation when it moves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, water

Since water molecules are dipoles and get excited by microwave radiation I wonder if the opposite is true and water can act as an electromagnetic emitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I recall, it's water molecules precessing in a magnetic field that produce the radiation detected during an MRI.

Comment: Yeah but my question is about liquid dipoles that are not statically bound to each other, being accelerated because of turbulence or whatever.

Comment: I just checked and found that ice is not magnetic. That would suggest that in the liquid state, thermal agitation would cause water dipoles to be randomly oriented. Any dipole radiation would probably be undetectable.

Comment: I asked in another question if water molecules took a specific orientation with regards to the flow, as I am not convinced in case of translation movement molecules orientations take a perfectly flat distribution.